# How to mock 'Display' in googletest?

Tags: x11, googletest

In my program, using the API `XOpenDisplay` to get a `Display`.  Then using the `Display` to get some `XResource`. Like that:

```
Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(0);

char *resourceString = XResourceManagerString(dpy); 

...

XCloseDisplay(dpy);
```

If you want to do googletest on this program，how should I mock `Display` or other X11 resource?

Comment: To make code testable you need to exclude all system calls from it. If tested functions consume Display - you can create DisplayOwner interface which will be mocked for test.